# Tomcat disable session not working

Tags: session, tomcat, keycloak, jsessionid

I have several apps deployed in Tomcat 7, and use Keycloak to manage user login and logout of these apps.  Logout does not work i.e., does not log the user out and redirect to Keycloak's login page.  Then I found the JSESSIONID cookie is still present, once I deleted the JSESSIONID cookie, the logout link works as expected.  So I tried to disable Tomcat's session by putting

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```

in the header of my apps' JSP pages. Unfortunately, this still does not seem to disable Tomcat's session, I still see JSESSIONID cookie present. I am wondering if anyone has a solution to this problem? I believe the presence of the Tomcat session interferes with the Keycloak's SSO session, and causes Keycloak logout to not work. This has to be a common problem Keycloak users encounter, Tomcat is so widely used for web apps.

Would appreciate any tips on how we should handle this!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have specific experience with Keycloak, however, there's a principle that applies to most if not all Single-Sign-On (or external authentication) solutions:

SSO identifies a user and removes the burden of knowing passwords from typical applications. When a user signs in, an application server is often detached from the actual SSO system, thus it will need to cache the user once they're identified, just as if the user identified itself with a classic login.

On the logout side, you can either log out of the application itself (tomcat in this case) or you can log out of the SSO system (which seems to be what you're doing here). With the later approach, you're running into the problem of "Single Sign Out": Logging out of the SSO system should invalidate all sessions that once were initiated with the associated login. As I know it, the SSO system needs to keep track of all of the systems that have signed on through it and trigger an explicit logout there.

I can't tell you how to implement this in Keycloak, but hope that the general principle helps guiding you towards the solution:

The use or non-use of a session on Tomcat's side has nothing to do with the problem: You might have applications that legitimately store information in a session in addition to the signed in user - those applications should continue to work even if you're not comparing passwords in tomcat itself.

**Edit**, after your comment:

If this one page doesn't trigger the use of a session, any other code (e.g. the code that processes your login) still might trigger a session and then later delegate to the page that doesn't want to use a session.

I'd expect that you'll have to disable sessions in Tomcat's configuration e.g. through providing a custom ["Manager" implementation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/manager.html). It looks like the default ones do not expect you to completely ignore sessions. As I've outlined above, I'd also expect sessions to be required even if you're not logging in through Tomcat itself.

Another way to avoid sessions (this is the indicator why I don't expect "no session" config to work) is to avoid calling any method on request/response that would trigger the automatic creation of a session. And it seems that you have such a method somewhere in your app.

(someone correct me if I'm wrong. This is mostly my educated expectation as I've never looked at this requirement)

Comment: This does not really answer my question.  The question has less to do with Keycloak, more to do with Tomcat.  In short, I just want to find out how to disable Tomcat's session.  I tried one way (<%@ page session="false" %>), and it did not work.